# Sqlalchemy - override database engine in tests

Tags: testing, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have the following sqlalchemy initialization in my application

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine(config.DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

I would like to override the database engine in tests (pytest) to sqlite (in memory)

Is it possible to do this per test ?

My goal is that each test case should start with empty (in-meomry-sqlite) database.